# Can "Abgewöhnen" be used with a noun not derived from a verb?

Tags: noun

Is the following sentence correct (could you please suggest a better alternative):

> Ich will mir die Backwaren abgewöhnen.

or

> Ich will mir die Gewohnheit des Essens von Backwaren abgewöhnen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure both sentences are correct. You can use a concrete noun as long as what you're doing with it/them is implied. The most common concrete noun used is cigarettes: *Ich werde mir die Zigaretten abgewöhnen.* Though it's more common to say smoking instead: *Ich werde mir das Rauchen abgewöhnen.*

But the second sentence sounds awkward and wordy to me, something like "I want to break the habit of eating baked goods," instead of "I want to give up baked goods." What else would you be doing with the baked goods besides eating them? And if it wasn't a habit then why would it be so difficult to stop?

Fun fact: You can also use *abgewöhnen* with *Akzent*; I guess having an accent is like having a bad habit you need to give up.

Comment: The reasoning in the second paragraph is flawed. 1. A wordy verbal phrase ("the eating of baked goods") is not present in the source text ("das Rauchen"). It's not incorrect if *Zigaretten rauchen* is implied, and further *das Rauchen von Zigaretten*, where the determiner ("von") is questionable (*? Ich rauche von den Zigaretten*). 2. Of course you wouldn't say "I want to stop eating. Period". 3. Strict absence could imply not selling it, not talking about it ...

Comment: @vectory: By "the second sentence" I meant *Ich will mir die Gewohnheit des Essens von Backwaren abgewöhnen.* I apologize if that was confusing. I agree that *Ich werde mir das Rauchen abgewöhnen* is not unnecessarily wordy, but I was trying to say *Gewohnheit des Essens* is implied by context and can be dropped without losing the meaning.

Answer (score -1):

Abgewöhnen kann man sich nur eine Gewohnheit. Eine Gewohnheit ist immer eine Tätigkeit - insofern kann man strenggenommen sich nur Tätigkeiten abgewöhnen.

In der Umgangssprache kann man sicher einen Satz wie "Ich will mir die Backwaren abgewöhnen" formulieren - jedoch ist das im Prinzip eine Ellipse, die die Tätigkeit (das Essen der Backwaren) impliziert und deshalb auch verständlich ist.

Insofern ist der zweite Satz korrekt, wenn auch mMn. unnötig kompliziert formuliert. Typisch würde man das etwa so formulieren:

> Ich möchte mir das Naschen dieser Backwaren abgewöhnen.

> Ich möchte mir mal abgewöhnen, dauernd diese Backwaren zu essen

> Ich muss mir mal dieses Schokolade-Essen abgewöhnen

Comment: Deine Satzbeispiele hören sich (obwohl sie definitiv korrekt sind) für mich sehr geschraubt und redundant an. Dass man mit Backwaren (die man sich abgewöhnt) nichts wesentlich anderes machen kann, als sie zu verputzen, ist, wie du richtig schreibst, eigentlich klar.

Comment: Ja... Vielleicht eher "ich muss mir mal dies Schokolade - essen abgewöhnen"

Comment: Danke Alle für die Kommentare. Eigentlich möchte ich Sätze formulieren, in denen sowohl das Dativ- als auch das Akkusativobjekt vorkommt. Insofern scheint der Satz von @planetmaker - "ich muss mir mal dies Schokolade - essen abgewöhnen" - treffend.

Comment: Ganz im Gegenteil kann man sich eine Gewohnheit eben NICHT abgewöhnen. Abgewöhnen kann man sich das, was man zur Gewohnheit (gemacht) hat. Wenn man sich zB das Rauchen abgewöhnt, dann raucht man nicht mehr, wenn man sich die Gewohnheit des Rauchens abgewöhnt, dann hat man früher regelmäßig geraucht und tut es jetzt hin und wieder (eben ohne daß es eine Gewohnheit wäre).